# How to use an Aurelia JSPM plugin with WebPack

Tags: webpack, chart.js, aurelia

I would like to knnow how to use an `Aurelia` plugin that was made to be used with `JSPM`. I would like to use it with `WebPack`. The plugin is [Aurelia-Chart](https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-chart) and is working great when using it locally in my `src` folder with `.feature('aurelia-chart')` (inside the `main.js` file) but of course the end goal is to use it externally via the `.plugin('aurelia-chart')`.

I believe that the biggest problem is that the plugin is called via an `index.js` file which is under `node_modules\aurelia-chart\dist\commonjs\index.js`. This `index.js` is referencing some other files in deeper directory and I think `WebPack` is getting lost with the path of these other files.

Inside the `index.js`

```
aurelia.globalResources("./elements/chart-element", "./attributes/chart-attribute");
```

There error that I am getting is

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-chart/elements/chart-element'.
```

I did try to create the plugin from scratch via the [Aurelia Skeleton-Plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin) but even the skeleton is built (unless I misunderstood) to be used via `JSPM` and doesn't handle well `WebPack` or `RequireJS`. I also try to remove all the folders and change the paths references to be within the same folder but that didn't help.

I also found this [Github issue](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/344) to be very similar to my issue and the answer to that issue, near the end of the issue, was to use [Resource and bundling configuration](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack#resource-and-bundling-configuration) like so:

```
// (package.json)
"aurelia": {
    "build": {
        "resources": [
            {
                "path": "users",
                "bundle": "users",
                "lazy": true
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

I tried reusing this piece of code and change it for the following:

```
// (package.json)
    "aurelia-chart": {
        "build": {
            "resources": [
                "./~/aurelia-chart/dist/commonjs/elements/chart-element",
                "./~/aurelia-chart/dist/commonjs/attributes/chart-attribute",
                "./~/aurelia-chart/dist/commonjs/observers/model-observer"
            ]
        }
    }
```

I spent 2 days trying to get it working externally with the `.plugin('aurelia-chart')` via all kind of bundling process (I took example from `aurelia-auth`, `aurealia-authentication`, `aurelia-animator-css`.) but none of my attempts worked.

Please note again that it does work locally via the `.feature('aurelia-chart')`. I would like to help the author and the community to use this great plugin (and possibly my own plugins in the future). I have opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-chart/issues/14) about the problem, and the author is very great and very helpful but is also clueless on how to make this working in bundling like `WebPack` or `RequireJS` (CLI). I would like to have a solution that works with both `WebPack` and the new `Aurelia CLI` for bundling.

Comment: In build resources try: `aurelia-chart/elements/chart-element`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I get the same error. There's 1 thing that I am not clear though, where do I put the resources in the `package.json` file? I've put mine completely at the end of the file, but I wonder if it goes under the `dependencies` and if so then how do I write it?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// (package.json)
"aurelia": {
  "build": {
    "resources": [
      "aurelia-chart/elements/chart-element",
      "aurelia-chart/attributes/chart-attribute"
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks that almost finally worked there's 1 little missing piece in your answer. There is 2 resources to include, could you please add `"aurelia-chart/attributes/chart-attribute"` to the resources array (`chart-element` is still first resource) and I will accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was going to be simple :)

Answer (score 0):

for latest aurelia-cli (0.32.0) + webpack use chart.js 2.5.0 and use global resources in main.js

```
aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-chart'));
aurelia.use.globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-chart/elements/chart-element'));
aurelia.use.globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-chart/attributes/chart-attribute'));
```